# Super-light weight database engine to distribute part of tiny PHP script

Tags: php, database

I am looking for a super-light weight open-source database engine (could be a library that mimics one) to be packaged part of a tiny PHP script distributed to people without `sudo` access. Basic CRUD, no need for any complicated implementations with string search, etc.

I found [txtSQL](http://txtsql.com) (uses flat files, which I believe is the way to go) but hesitant to use it given the last time it was updated (2005-03).

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 7):

[sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) gives you a platform-independent file format and is heavily regression tested and widely used. It is also available in PHP via [SQLite3](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php).

Comment: Doesn't that require some kinda `sudo` permissions to build PHP with the extension? Forgot to mention, needs to work with PHP4/5. SQLite3 comes by default w/ PHP5.3 but not before... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is about as light as you can get and it does everything via text files.

Comment: "is does everything via text files": really? since when?!

Comment: how about always.  the .db file is just a formatted text file, open it up sometimes.

Comment: The myth of databases is that they aren't text files.

Comment: -1 Have you tried opening a sqlite3 db with a text editor? It's not a text file...